# husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 127 (error)

Tags: reactjs, git, husky

I'm using `husky v8` and when I want to commit file changes on the repository I get this git error

```
.husky/pre-commit: line 4: npx: command not found
husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 127 (error)
husky - command not found in PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/libexec/git-core:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

here is `pre-commit` file

```
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

npx lint-staged
```

this is `prepare` command in `package.json`

```
"prepare": "husky install",
```

I'm guessing I should define an environment variable

Comment: 127 most is "command not found" which is also the first line of your error message: "npx: command not found"

Comment: So I guess the solution is to install `npx` on your system

Comment: @knittl Looks like `npx` is installed already. When I run `sudo npm i -g npx` it tells me the file already exists

Comment: And when you type `npx` in your terminal? The error message is pretty clear about the fact that the binary is not found in `PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/libexec/git-core:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` (the third line of the error)

Comment: I get the same error when trying to commit from within Visual Studio 2022. But I don't get an error when trying to commit from within Visual Studio Code, or command line git.

As if Visual Studio 2022 uses different git installation or different path.